# `embeddedFile` warns during compilation while using quasiquotes

Tags: scala, scala-macros, scala-quasiquotes

After I started using quasiquotes for Scala 2.10 via SBT plugin I have warnings as follows:

```
[warn] embeddedFile--QuasiquoteCompat.scala@e97d744663044acca2f60c8e99547f14:320: Adapting argument list by inserting (): leaky (Object-receiving) target makes this especially dangerous.
[warn]         signature: ConstantExtractor.apply(value: Any): Constants.this.Constant
[warn]   given arguments: <none>
[warn]  after adaptation: ConstantExtractor((): Unit)
[warn]               DefDef(NoMods, newTermName("$init$"), List(), List(List()), TypeTree(), u.Block(lvdefs, Literal(Constant())))))
[warn]                                                                                                                       ^
[warn] embeddedFile--QuasiquoteCompat.scala@e97d744663044acca2f60c8e99547f14:329: Adapting argument list by inserting (): leaky (Object-receiving) target makes this especially dangerous.
[warn]         signature: ConstantExtractor.apply(value: Any): Constants.this.Constant
[warn]   given arguments: <none>
[warn]  after adaptation: ConstantExtractor((): Unit)
[warn]               DefDef(constrMods, nme.CONSTRUCTOR, List(), vparamss1, TypeTree(), u.Block(lvdefs ::: List(superCall), Literal(Constant())))))
[warn]                                                                                                                                      ^
```

How to interpret these warns?

What am I doing wrong?

What can I do about them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed in the 2.10.3-RC1 version of paradise. If you need to use 2.10.2, please let me know, and I'll publish an updated version for 2.10.2.